# Meteor Collection Hooks Error: Property 'before' does not exist on type 'Collection<>'

Tags: mongodb, meteor, collections, hook

I am trying integrate meteor collection hooks in my project. I instaled it:

```
meteor add matb33:collection-hooks
```

and added it to tsconfig.json:

```
 "types": [
            "meteor-typings",
            "@types/underscore",
            "@types/meteor-collection-hooks"
        ]
```

in package.json  in dependencies I have:

```
  "@types/meteor-collection-hooks": "^0.8.3",
```

in both/collection in problem.collection.ts I have method "Problems.before.insert" - "before" is underlined and show the error which I wrote in title.  (This method get problemId from last inserted object,  increase it, and insert increased Id to new creating object). Code in problem.collection.ts:

```
import { MongoObservable } from "meteor-rxjs";
import { Problem } from "../models/problem.model";


export const Problems = new MongoObservable.Collection<Problem>("problems");



function loggedIn() {
    return !!Meteor.user();
  }

Problems.allow({
    insert: loggedIn,
    update: loggedIn,
    remove: loggedIn
});


Problems.before.insert(function (problemId, problem) {
    let lastProblem = Problems.find({}, { sort: { _id: -1 }, limit: 1 }).fetch()[0];
    let lastProblemId = lastProblem.problemSecondId++;
    problem.problemSecondId = lastProblemId;
});
```

I dont know, what I do wrong. It looks like, that package isnt installed...?

Comment: Have you tried to use the recommended implementation in the docs: https://guide.meteor.com/collections.html#hooks

Comment: I tried it. This attitude didint work for me too. I am very unhappy. You can give me advice.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51793165/before-insert-meteor-extension-mongoobservable-get-last-object-from-mongod/51857184#51857184