# before.insert / Meteor extension / mongoObservable / get last object from mongoDB = "undefined"

Tags: angular, mongodb, meteor, insert, hook

I have this code extension of insert method in problems.collection.ts. I need find last inserted object, get lastId and increase it.

Every object has own unique ID, but I want create in every object "problemSecondId" that will be more suitable and will be presented to user in my app.

So when I create first "Problem" in collection, I get console.log "undefined" in variable "lastProblem" and object is created with "problemSecondId: 1". When I create second "Problem", I get again "undefined" and second "Problem" is created with "problemSecondId: 1" too!!! I tried a lot of things.

Code behaves, that the query "findOne" returns "undefined" so I think, that mistake is in query, or possible mistake can be that collection "Problems" is not Mongo.Collection but MongoObservable.Collection... ? Can somebody help me?  thnx.

```
import { MongoObservable } from "meteor-rxjs";
import { Problem } from "../models/problem.model";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { Mongo } from "meteor/mongo";


class ProblemCollection extends Mongo.Collection {
    insert(problem, callback) {
      if (!problem.problemSecondId) {
        let lastProblem = Problems.findOne({}, { sort: { problemSecondId: -1 }});
        console.log(lastProblem);
        if (lastProblem){
          let lastProblemId = lastProblem.problemSecondId++;
          problem.problemSecondId = lastProblemId;
        } else {
          problem.problemSecondId = 1;
        }

      }

      return super.insert(problem, callback);
    }
  }



let problems = new ProblemCollection("problems");

export const Problems = new MongoObservable.Collection<Problem>(problems);


function loggedIn() {
    return !!Meteor.user();
  }

Problems.allow({
    insert: loggedIn,
    update: loggedIn,
    remove: loggedIn
});
```

Comment: Hi again, a couple of things: No need to delete a question and ask pretty much the same. If you have something to add, you can edit your existing question. Now, to the topic: are you absolutely certain that your query result in `lastProblem` is `undefined` the second time or are you deducing this from the fact that your second `problem` has a `lastProblemId` of 1 as well? Because I see nothing wrong with your query, but see an issue with your code that will cause the exact behavior (both documents with `lastProblemId` of `1`).

Comment: thnx for answer. What I read about "findOne" (it does .fetch()[0] ), so this should return certain object in but in console.log I see in both situation undefined, so I think it is executed "else" part of code. Yes, I checked it in database, each created problem has "problemSecondId: 1"

Comment: do you check in server console that console.log(lastProblem) is undefined ?

Comment: I have code above in both/collections/problems.collection.ts. The console.log in this case shows output in browser console. So I assume, that I should copy code to server/imports/main.ts ??? Or server/imports/publications/problems.ts ??

Comment: Check rather the terminal console and see if it show also undefined. The fact it is undefined in the browser console can simply be that you do not send this data in your publication

Comment: but yes try moving the code to server side

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a good example for misuse of the postfix [increment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_()) (`++`) operator.

```
let x = 5;
let y = x++; // x = 6, y = 5
```

The expression involving the postfix operator evaluates to the value *before* the increment.

Thing is, there was no real need for it in the first place. You have no need to increment `lastProblem`'s `problemSecondId` property, since all you wanted  to do is set that same property of the `problem` object.

Simply using:

```
problem.problemSecondId = lastProblem.problemSecondId + 1;
```

would be clearer, in my opinion, and has the advantage of actually doing what you intend.

The fact that your query returns `undefined` on the client does not necessarily imply that this is the case on the server as well, since the data available on the client may not reflect the database contents.

As a side note, take into account that you may run into a race condition, where 2 `problem`s are created at close proximity, and both can get the same `problemSecondId`, since the combination of actions (`find` and `update`) is not atomic and there are no locks in use.

Answer (score 0):

I added to the code "Meteor.isServer" condition to execute code only on server. Result is that I have NO output in console and terminal (and in MongoDb is created object and "problemSecondId" completely missing). So I am very unhappy with solving this problem. Couldn´t be problem with,  that problems.collection.ts is situated in meteort/both/collections/... I think, that is right, because collection is used both (client and server). Edited code below:

```
import { MongoObservable } from "meteor-rxjs";
import { Problem } from "../models/problem.model";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { Mongo } from "meteor/mongo";


class ProblemCollection extends Mongo.Collection {

      insert(problem, callback) {

              if (Meteor.isServer) {

                    if (!problem.problemSecondId) {
                      let lastProblem = Problems.findOne({}, { sort: { problemSecondId: -1 } });
                      console.log(lastProblem);
                      if (lastProblem) {
                        console.log('xxx');
                        let lastProblemId = lastProblem.problemSecondId + 1;
                        problem.problemSecondId = lastProblemId;
                      } else {
                        console.log('yyy')
                        problem.problemSecondId = 1;
                      }

                    }
              }

        return super.insert(problem, callback);

      }


 }



    let problems = new ProblemCollection("problems");

    export const Problems = new MongoObservable.Collection<Problem>(problems);


    Problems.allow({
      insert: loggedIn,
      update: loggedIn,
      remove: loggedIn
    });



    function loggedIn() {
        return !!Meteor.user();
    }
```